# .FirstOrDefault() is returning null on a non-empty IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

What are the possible reasons for `.FirstOrDefault()` to return null if a collection has at least one item? This is using Sitefinity and the videos manager is built into the CMS.

**Code:**

```
    protected virtual Video GetVideo(Guid id)
    {
        LibrariesManager librariesManager = LibrariesManager.GetManager();
        IQueryable<Video> videos = librariesManager.GetVideos(); // Five Items
        IQueryable<Video> x = videos.Where(d => d.Id == id); // Correctly filters to one item with the matching Id
        Video video = x.FirstOrDefault(); // null


        if (video != null)
        {
            video = librariesManager.Lifecycle.GetLive(video) as Video;
        }

        return video; // <- Breakpoint is set here.
    }
```

**Result for `x`:**
[image: Result for x]

**Result for `video`:**
[image: Result for video]

I've have also tried simply using `.First()` as well as converting it into a List and taking the first index using `x[0]`. The collection has an item each time, but video is always null;

For the record, I am following [this guide](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-query-videos), and split the query into multiple variables to see what's going on at each step.

**Edit:**
To clarify, `videos` itself is a collection of five items and the `.Where` correctly filters to the single item matching the `Id`, which then gets assigned to `x`. `Video video = x.FirstOrDefault();` is the first instance where the actual result is different from the expected.

Comment: Probably you are checking it before the value is assigned to it.

Comment: *Based on your update* - You reassign the `video` in the `if` block and do a cast so those are 2 additional reasons that the `video` instance could be `null` at your break point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reassign `video` in the `if`  block if it is not null. With that re-assignment you are also casting the result. Both of those could be reasons why `video` is null when you hit your break point.

- `librariesManager.Lifecycle.GetLive(video)` <- could return a `null` value
- The result from `librariesManager.Lifecycle.GetLive(video)` could return an instance that cannot be cast to `Video` which would result in a `null` value being assigned.

```
if (video != null) // so not null here
{
    video = librariesManager.Lifecycle.GetLive(video) as Video;
}
return video; // <- Breakpoint is set here.
```

*I am thinking you have your `if` statement's `null` check backwards (check for null instead of not null) but that is a guess as we don't know what `Lifecycle.GetLive` actually does.*

Comment: This was it. Thank you.

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen I deleted my answer since this one is now better. I also thought, at first, that you had the `if` check backwards. But I think now that the meaning of the `if` is to do a "conversion" of `video` in the case where `video` is not null. You could get the same logic with `if (video == null) { return null; } return librariesManager.Lifecycle.GetLive(video) as Video;` It depends on taste (some people do not like two `return` in one method), but that might make it more clear where the `null` comes from.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yeah, that part is more of a Sitefinity thing, so I won't bother you all with it here :)

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen The lesson learned is that no matter what line of the method you point to during debugging, the debugger will show the value that variable has __now__, at the time where we break execution, __not__ the value that variable had when control was back at that line (that you point to) in the program.

Answer (score 0):

1. First check the videos list have one item that is exactly your item ( with d.Id is exactly that parameter id)
2. try use this

   ```
   var videos = LibraryManager.GetVideos();
   var video  = videos.where(d => d.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

Comment: OP updated his question, you may want to delete this.